# SWI-Prolog list result

Tags: prolog

I'm coding in prolog, but I have a issue. How can I make that the answer appears just once? for example I just want that "X = uni, X = uca, X = unam" but instead it just keep showing me the options repeatedly.

This is some of it:

```
is(uni, college).
is(uca, college).
is(unan, college).

is(computation, carrer).
```

In this part I'm assigning available places to the carrer

```
has(computation, available_places, 200).
```

and finally assigning the carrer to a college

```
offers(unan, computation).
offers(uni, computation).
offers(uca, computation).
```

and I make the query like this:

```
which(X):- is(X, college), is(Y, carrer), offers(X, Y),has(Y, available_places, Z), Z<300.
```

but the result as I said at the beggining, show me the names of the college repeadtedly. Any idea how to solve this? D:

Comment: Please do *not* use `is/2` here. Prolog already has an `is`, and this is used to resolve computational expressions.

Comment: I can not reproduce this by the way. If I rename your `is/2` to `isa/2`, it works fine.